# JavaFx: Can't call Main class in another package? (IntelliJIdea)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I just started creating a JavaFx project using intelliJ that runs successfully. I'm using JDK 11 and I have a module-info created. However, it's not running anymore when I created another package and moved the Main class.

Main class:

```
package com.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/src/sample/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

module-info

```
module ProjectJavaFxA {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens sample;
}
```

Controller class

```
package sample;

public class Controller {
}
```

[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOzHH.jpg)

Comment: Try to move your sample folder into com.main

Comment: I intentionally created another package and separated it into fxml. How can I make this work without moving anything?

Comment: hmm .. why don't you follow the instructions in the error message?

Comment: You can separate your fxml file in resources folder, and mark this folder as resources in IntelliJ

Comment: If you are not using Kotlin in this project - does it help to disable the **Kotlin** bundled plugin (Settings/Preferences | Plugins)?

Comment: @Andrey I have disabled the Kotlin plugin but still an error. Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the issue by exporting your package `sample` in your `module-info.java` file, update your file like so and it should fix the issue -

**module-info.java**

```
module ProjectJavaFxA {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    exports sample;
    opens com.main;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still getting an error in  `exports sample; `  (Error: java: package is empty or does not exist: sample)

Comment: Can you post your project structure to the question?

Comment: Even same problem after I exchanged sample to com.main

Comment: Can you try adding  requires kotlin.stdlib above requires javafx.fxml in your module-info.java

Comment: Error: Module not found kotlin.stdlib

Comment: It working now. .    ' exports com.main; opens sample; '

Comment: A while ago  ' exports com.main; opens sample; ' wasn't working but suddenly it works after I run it all over again... kotlin.stlib isn't necessary. Thanks for the help!